# Paginating search results with Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I've been trying to do this for the last 2 hours with no success, I'm sure it's something really simple :)

So, I have form where users can search things based on some keywords. Here's the form code:

```
<%= form_tag search_by_description_path,:method => "get" do %>
        <div class="column span-3">
            <label>Search</label>
        </div>

        <div class="column span-5">
            <input type="text" name="search_keywords" id="search_keywords"/>
        </div>

        <div class="column span-6">
            <%= collection_select :category,:id,Category.all,:id,:name,:include_blank => "Everything" %>
        </div>

        <div class="column span-3">
            <%= submit_tag "search" %>
        </div>

    <% end %>
```

I have this in the `routes.rb`:

```
get "search_by_description" => "search#search_by_description",:as => "search_by_description"
```

I have this in the controller:

```
def search_by_description
    category    = params[:category_id]
    kw          = params[:search_keywords]
    @results = Posts.where("description LIKE ?","%#{kw}%").page(params[:page])
end
```

Ignore the fact that I'm not keeping track of `category_id`. In my view I have this:

```
<%= render "results",:locals => {:results => @results} %>
<%= paginate(@results) %>
```

The problem is, the when I go to the second page, I don't see anything displayed. Looking in the console, I noticed something that for the 1st page, the following SQL gets generated:

```
 SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (description LIKE '%lorem%') ORDER BY id LIMIT 25 OF
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE (description LIKE '%lorem%')
```

while for the second only:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE (description LIKE '%lorem%') LIMIT 25 OFFSET 25
```

Please give me some suggestions, I don't want to resort to writing my own pagination :)

Comment: Are you sure your search returns more than 25 matches?

Comment: Yes. I have  43 objects stored, and 41 returned by the query. I find it strange that for the first page all 41 get returned, and for the second none.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I don't see anything wrong with your code (not saying it isn't there, I just don't see it). The SQL for page two looks right -- Kaminari takes that extra line of SQL in the first request to count how many total pages there are, but then it's got that in session I believe so it doesn't need to query for it again.  have you tried just copying the SQL that is generated for page 2 in your console to see what is returned? Also, consider sticking in a debug(@results) somewhere on your view and see what it says.

Comment: Ok , something very strange happens. Very strange. If I put the `debug(@results)` in the view, the second page gets paginated too. If I remove it, it's gone. Now I am totally lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause of this problem is ActiveRecord 3.0's bug, which will be fixed in ActiveRecord 3.1 https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d5994ee 
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/28c73f0

And I did a monkeypatch on Kaminari to work with ActiveRecord 3.0 https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/9d0eebe38e2a22fb8100e491a6d94839d76c868f/lib/kaminari/models/active_record_relation_methods.rb#L7-11

In short, updating your Kaminari gem to the newest one will fix your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug, or misuse, from my side. I had this in my view:

```
<% if results.size > 0 %>
   ...
<% else %>
   <p>No results found</p>
<% end %>
```

and this was always going on the `else` clause for pages different than the first. If I change the `results.size` to `results.all.size` it works. However, I don't understand why it doesn't work directly with `results.size`.

Comment: Hmm, well, glad you found it!